# Can you take a hand luggage and a small bag with Vueling?

Tags: air-travel, hand-luggage, vueling

RyanAir allows you to take a handluggage and a small bag with you on the plane.  The policy for Vueling is less specific.  Based on this page - http://www.edreams.com/blog/luggage-restrictions-by-airline/, it says that you can also take:

> In addition, each passenger is allowed to carry one of the following
>   items at no additional charge: a small purse or wallet, a coat or
>   travel blanket, a laptop, or camera.

The official website at http://www.vueling.com/en/vueling-services/prepare-your-trip/luggage does not mention anything about another bag / laptop etc.

Do you think I can take with me a small bag as well, like a small backpack?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This [April 19, 2015 post](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/24686818-post4.html) in a [Vueling second carry on bag](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/iberia-airlines-iberia-plus/1673046-vueling-second-carry-bag.html) thread on flyertalk shows a boarding pass which indicates a personal item is allowed:

[image: boarding pass]

and others posted in positive too. Unless something changed in the last year (and there's no trace of that) you are good to go.